# MySQL seems to ignore --host argument

Tags: mysql, ssh

I need to connect to a MySQL database on a server to which I do not have access through the firewall. I do however have SSH access to another server which is allowed through the firewall on my target server.

I have SSH'd into the latter (let's say host1) and then I am attempting to execute the following command:

```
mysql --host=host2 --user=username --password=password
```

I get the following response:

```
Access denied for user 'username'@'host1' (using password: YES)
```

Why is it trying to connect to host1 (i.e itself)?

NB: I'm not using `localhost` anywhere here.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. It's a legitimate misunderstanding. If I knew the reason, I wouldn't need to ask the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the error, it is saying that the user `username` connecting from `host1` was denied access. The error comes from `host2`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it was an error coming from host 2.

Comment: This error was really holding me up, even after various GRANT option were given this still wouldn't allow me to connect. I ended dropping the user and using the IP address with the GRANT option.
`GRANT USAGE, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, INDEX, DROP, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES ON myself.* TO 'myself'@'123.123.123.10';`

Answer (score 4):

The error is actually saying "You're trying to use `username` **from** `host1`".

You'll need to add permissions for `username` on `host1`. Can you post `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'` from while logged into MySQL as root on `host2`?

Edit: Ninja'd :)

Comment: Sorry bout that :)

Answer (score -2):

I had this error because of the wrong password I used for the database. This was the case for the Version Version of mysql is 5.1.61.

So ensure the password of your database is correct.

Comment: In this case, the accepted answer is correct.  This can be the cause of that error, yes, but that wasn't the question.